# TrueColor CData contains element out of range

Tags: matlab

While working with detecting discontinuities and breakdown points I recieved the following error:

> TrueColor CData contains element out of range 0.0 <= value <= 1.0

My code is:

```
X=imread('D:\project\Dataset\84130398.png');

level = 1;
[c,s] = wavedec2(X,level,'coif2');
[chd1,cvd1,cdd1] = detcoef2('all',c,s,level);

figure('Color','white'), image(chd1),colormap(map);
title('Horizontal Edges');
```

My input image is:

[image: Input image]

Comment: Please provide the full error and stack trace.

Comment: You are trying to display `chd1` as an image ... but it contains values way outside the range of a _TrueColor_ image: `[min(chd1(:)) max(chd1(:))]` return `-270  275`. Either normalize the matrix (bound it in the interval `[0 1]`, or treat these values as they are: _wavelet coefficients_ ... not _image_.

Comment: Thank you for your help i tried this code for normalize                       mmin = min(chd1(:));
mmax = max(chd1(:));
chd1 = (chd1-mmin) ./ (mmax-mmin);                                                                and its working